# Nodejs exec not such file or directory

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

[
  {
    token: '1015010204030817080302030300',
  },
].forEach(async ({ token }) => {
  exec(
    `ffmpeg -i ${token}.mp4 -vf "fps=35,scale=414:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen" ${token}.png`,
    (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        //some err occurred
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      }
    }
  );
  exec(
    `ffmpeg -t 29 -i ${token}.mp4 -i ${token}.png -filter_complex "fps=35,scale=414:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" ${token}.gif`,
    (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        //some err occurred
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

but I get the following error: `1015010204030817080302030300.mp4: No such file or directory`

here is the complete error

```
Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -i 1015010204030817080302030300.mp4 -vf "fps=35,scale=414:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen" 1015010204030817080302030300.png
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4.1_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
1015010204030817080302030300.mp4: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'ffmpeg -i 1015010204030817080302030300.mp4 -vf "fps=35,scale=414:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen" 1015010204030817080302030300.png'
}
Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -t 29 -i 1015010204030817080302030300.mp4 -i 1015010204030817080302030300.png -filter_complex "fps=35,scale=414:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" 1015010204030817080302030300.gif
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4.1_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
1015010204030817080302030300.mp4: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:659:12) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'ffmpeg -t 29 -i 1015010204030817080302030300.mp4 -i 1015010204030817080302030300.png -filter_complex "fps=35,scale=414:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" 1015010204030817080302030300.gif'
```

But if I copy paste the complete comando from the error and paste on the console it execute without any errors. So I assuming that the problem is with Nodejs but I don't know what is happening I also try to créate and asyncronus exec but I get a `Unhandled promise rejection.` error

Comment: What is your CWD, where are you video files located?

Comment: What directory is the script in? are you running `node` from? and is the mp4 file in?

Comment: Does the second command depend on output from the first command?

Comment: the video file is inside a Folder with the name "video"

Comment: @Matt yes, I have to generase the pallet before generate the gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "current working directory" of the Node process is important when using [`exec` as it defaults to `process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback)

The two commands:

```
$ node /path/to/my/script.js
```

and

```
$ cd /path/to/my
$ node ./script.js
```

Will cause `exec` to start in different directories which impacts the relative path being supplied to `ffmpeg`.

Another way to fix this is to be specific with full directory paths for `ffmpeg` which is what I have presented below.

Additionally, `exec` is an asynchronous function. The function will return before the results are available so you need to wait for the results. This is much easier with promises and `await` than your example codes callback API.

```
const path = require('path')
const util = require('util')
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec)

async function runCmd(cmd, directory){
  console.log('Run command "%s" in directory "%s"', cmd, directory)
  try {
    const options = {}
    if (directory) {
      options.cwd = directory
    }
    const res = await exec(cmd, options)
    console.debug('stdout', res.stdout)
    console.debug('stderr', res.stderr)
    if ( res.exitCode !== 0 ) {
      const err = new Error(`Run command failed with exit code ${res.exitCode}`)
      err.cmd = cmd
      err.process = res
      throw err
    }
    console.log('Ran command "%s"', cmd)
    return res
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(`Run failed "${cmd}"`, directory, err)
    throw err
  }
}

async function processToken(token) {
  // `__dirname` is the directory of the current JS file. It might 
  // need '..' depending on your source structure or just a fully defined path
  const file_prefix = path.join(__dirname, 'video', token)
  // Check the file first
  await fs.stat(`${file_prefix}.mp4`)
  await runCmd(`ffmpeg -i "${file_prefix}.mp4" -vf "fps=35,scale=414:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen" "${file_prefix}.png"`)
  await runCmd(`ffmpeg -t 29 -i "${file_prefix}.mp4" -i "${file_prefix}.png" -filter_complex "fps=35,scale=414:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" "${file_prefix}.gif"`)
}

processToken('1015010204030817080302030300.mp4')
  .catch(err => { console.error(err); process.exit(1) })
```

I would also recommend using an async wrapper for [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) rather then `exec` as it provides more control and less "shell" gotchas, but I'll leave that for now.